# PHP require vs grails include

Tags: php, grails, groovy, require

I wanted to know the command which is exactly equal to php require in my GSP (Grails server pages) or in Groovy.

I know I can use `<g:include/>` but wanted to know is there any command which will fulfill php require in groovy/grails?

Comment: Can you provide more context about what you expect the `require()` equivalent to do within Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *exact* equivalent really depends on the context of what `require()` is being used for in the PHP script.

PHP and Servlet environments operate differently. Using `require()` in PHP simply locates another PHP script and executes it. That imperative-style operation doesn't apply as well to the more object-oriented Java/Grails/Servlets.

There are a couple of possible equivalents, depending on what you're trying to accomplish:

- **[`<g:include/>`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html)**

  > Includes the response of another controller/action or view in the
  >   current response

  e.g.

  ```
  <g:include controller="foo" action="bar"/>
  ```

  What this will do is invoke a different controller/action and insert the response into the current page. This would be similar to PHP if your `require()` was rendering some markup.
- **[View templates](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates)**:

  If you're just trying to include common pieces of markup in several pages, these might be what you're looking for. You can create template views and use [`<g:render/>`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html) to include them in your GSPs. I suspect this is what you're after, but see my "Update" below for some advice about this.
- **`@page import`**

  e.g.

  ```
  <% @page import="com.example.mypackage.MyClass" %>
  ```

  This will make `MyClass` available to the GSP, which would be similar to `require()` if the require was specifying some library classes or functions to be used in other PHP scripts. However, using this pretty much screams **code smell**, since almost anything you'd be using this for would be more appropriate in a controller action or a service.

**Update:**

Seeing your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647512/convert-wordpress-php-into-grails), I'll venture you're simply trying to include a common piece of GSP/HTML in several different views, which kind of goes against what Grails provides for you with its layouts and templates.

If you're trying to "require", say, "blog-header.php" in all of your GSPs, you'd more likely want to just include the contents of the header within a layout, e.g. `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp`, and then use that layout in the views that require the header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Grails uses sitemesh and wordpress uses different themes just getting my hands dirty with grails and looking for different options to start with. I dont like importing classes into my gsp's since its not a good practice. I will start using g:include and where ever I need some static context or variables I will go for controllers and other domain classes. I guess from cotrollers I can get context and from there I can read config information.

Comment: @springpress - I'm glad I could help. For the record, from what I understand, Wordpress' code base isn't the most fantastic example for elegant and organized code. However, that's just hearsay from others who I've talked about with it, so take it as you will; perhaps it's changed since then. Nonetheless, trying to do a straight 1:1 conversion from it to Grails might end up circumventing most of the conveniences Grails provides, so keep that in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try grails 'template'.

A template is a fragment of view that can be used any time in any view, this is to promove DRY..

```
<g:render template="myTemplate" model="['object1':object1,'object2':object2]" />
```

In this case should exists a GSP called _myTemplate.gsp and in this template is working with two objects, you could do a template with only content and no treating objects if you wish.

In the above call the template is invoked in a view in the same folder with the template but you could call it from another view in other folder:

```
<g:render template="other/myTemplate" model="['object1':object1,'object2':object2]" />
```

And the pattern for the name of template is the same...

Check it out...